# How to get the data of last five days from amazon simple db in iphone application

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I want to get the data from table last 5 days records I have seen examples they work fine for other data base but i am using amazon simple db so and sql razor I am using same query but it does not work and shows error

```
SELECT *  
FROM UserContentUsage    
WHERE ViewDateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SimpleDB stores everything as UTF-8 strings. All comparisons are done lexicographically. The dates should be in ISO 8601 format so that they can be properly compared in lexicographical order.

See [page](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1232/) for more detail.